# sed: Match this comma or that, but not both

Tags: sed, mysql

I have a huge mysql dump that I'm using sed to delete unneeded rows (very much faster than deleting from table) and each line of the dump is in the format

```
 INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ("somevalue", 0), ("anothervalue", 90), ("nospaces", 67), ("another", 0) ... ;
```

I only need rows with the 0 integer value, so I use this expression:

```
 sed -i 's/, ("[^ ]*", [1-9][0-9]*)//g' dump.sql
```

However, this doesn't match the very first row (see the comma in the expression) .. Is there anyway I can match either the comma in the beginning or end, but not both?

Comment: This should work fine, the only wrinkle can come from the spaces might be TABs. Use, `[[:blank:]] ` in place of a space in your regex.

Comment: @RakeshSharma it's the commas that are causing the problem. If I have a leading or trailing comma, it is no longer valid MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you don't rely on `,` in front of `()`, but instead rely on it after with `\?`. It doesn't really matter whether you have one or multiple spaces anyway. Something like that should do it for you:

```
sed -i 's/("[^ ]*", [1-9][0-9]*),\?//g; s/,\s*;/;/' dump.sql
```

Note that `\?` means that `,` is not a mandatory character. If it's not there, there still would be a match.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If the expression matches the very last row then I'll be left with an extra comma `... ("val", 0), ("anotherval",0),;` which is incorrect MySQL syntax :(

Comment: the you should add second `sed` expression to eliminate that. I updated the answer to demonstrate that as well.